# Swift: get substring of string, ignoring case and accents

Tags: swift, string, substring

I would like to extract a substring from a string, ignoring the accents and case.

For example, If the string is `Curaçao` and the input substring `aca`, it would split the string into three substrings : `Cur` (substring before the matching one), `aça` (matching substring) and `o` (remaining substring after the matching one).

I tried this code:

```
extension String {
    subscript(offset: Int) -> Character { self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)] }
    subscript(range: Range<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        let startIndex = index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        return self[startIndex..<index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.count)]
    }
    subscript(range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        let startIndex = index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        return self[startIndex..<index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.count)]
    }
    subscript(range: PartialRangeFrom<Int>) -> SubSequence { self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)...] }
    subscript(range: PartialRangeThrough<Int>) -> SubSequence { self[...index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)] }
    subscript(range: PartialRangeUpTo<Int>) -> SubSequence { self[..<index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)] }
    
    func highlight(substring: String) -> String {
        if let range = lowercased()
            .folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
            .range(of: substring
                    .lowercased()
                    .folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)) {
            let startPos = distance(from: startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
            let endPos = distance(from: startIndex, to: range.upperBound)
            let firstSubstring = self[..<startPos]
            let secondSubstring = self[range]
            let thirdSubstring = self[endPos...]
            return "\(firstSubstring)[\(secondSubstring)]\(thirdSubstring)"
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

However, when trying it:

`print("Curaçao".highlight(substring: "aca"))`

> Cur[aç]ao

Another example :

`print("Curaçaoçao".highlight(substring: "acaoca"))`

> Cur[açao]çao

What is causing this? Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you care if it returns it back WITH the case and accents? -- Does `print("Curaçao".highlight(substring: "aca"))` need to return `Cur[aça]o` or `Cur[aca]o`

Comment: @impression7vx, Yes, I need to get `Cur[aça]o` in return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [localizedStandardRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413574-localizedstandardrange) which is diacritic and case insensitive. Btw there is no need to convert the range to integer:

```
localizedStandardRange(of:)
```

> Finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string within the string by performing a case and diacritic insensitive, locale-aware search.

---

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func highlight<S: StringProtocol>(substring: S) -> SubSequence? {
        guard let range = localizedStandardRange(of: substring) else { return nil }
        return self[..<range.lowerBound] + "[" + self[range] + "]" + self[range.upperBound...]
    }
}
```

---

```
print("Curaçao".highlight(substring: "aca") ?? "")
print("Curaçaoçao".highlight(substring: "acaoca") ?? "")
```

---

This will print

> Cur[aça]o
> Cur[açaoça]o

---

If you just want to fix what's wrong with your extension just pass the proper options `caseInsensitive` and  `diacriticInsensitive` to your range method and don't convert the range to integer:

```
func highlight(substring: String) -> String {
    if let range = range(of: substring, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) {
        let firstSubstring = self[..<range.lowerBound]
        let secondSubstring = self[range]
        let thirdSubstring = self[range.upperBound]
        return "\(firstSubstring)[\(secondSubstring)]\(thirdSubstring)"
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

The reason why your method was failing was that you where searching the range and counting the distance on different strings.

Comment: I didn't know about `localizedStandardRange(of:)`, it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
extension String {
    subscript(_ range: CountableRange<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: max(0, range.lowerBound))
        let end = index(start, offsetBy: min(self.count - range.lowerBound, 
                                             range.upperBound - range.lowerBound))
        return String(self[start..<end])
    }

    subscript(_ range: CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: max(0, range.lowerBound))
        return String(self[start...])
    }

    func highlight(substring: String) -> String {
        let stringWithoutCaseOrLetters = self.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
        if let range = lowercased()
            .folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)
            .range(of: substring
                    .lowercased()
                    .folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current)) {
            let startPos:Int = stringWithoutCaseOrLetters.distance(from: startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
            let endPos:Int = stringWithoutCaseOrLetters.distance(from: startIndex, to: range.upperBound)
            let firstSubstring = self[0..<startPos]
            let secondSubstring = self[startPos..<endPos]
            let thirdSubstring = self[endPos...]
            return "\(firstSubstring)[\(secondSubstring)]\(thirdSubstring)"
        }
        return ""
    }
}

extension StringProtocol {
    func distance(of element: Element) -> Int? { firstIndex(of: element)?.distance(in: self) }
    func distance<S: StringProtocol>(of string: S) -> Int? { range(of: string)?.lowerBound.distance(in: self) }
}

extension Collection {
    func distance(to index: Index) -> Int { distance(from: startIndex, to: index) }
}

extension String.Index {
    func distance<S: StringProtocol>(in string: S) -> Int { string.distance(to: self) }
}

let string = "Curaçao"
print(string[0..<string.count])
print(string.highlight(substring: "aca"))

print("Curaçaoçao".highlight(substring: "acaoca"))
```